# Xamarin Costs to Publish on Google Play Store

Tags: android, xamarin

How much would it cost me to publish a small game developed in Xamarin using CocoSharp on Google Play Store. i already have a Google Store Account.
do i need a paid Xamarin subscription .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As announced in March 31, 2016 Xamarin is [free for everyone](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/).

So, if you already have a Google Play Store Account, its **free**.